# Is Liquibase 3.7 and 3.8 no longer supporting Java 7?

Tags: java, version, liquibase

Is there any documentation available about Java version requirements for Liquibase releases?
3.6.3 used to work fine on Java 7 JDK and we're having some problems with LB 3.7 and 3.8. 
Is there a dependency on Java 8? What changed?

Comment: Try Liquibase Website !

Comment: "We're having some problems" is almost as useful as "Have you tried some solutions?". Libraries tend to be backwards compatible, except in cases where they raise the baseline (e.g. library bytecode is Java 1.8, so you need at least 1.8 to use it).

Comment: One way is to look at the source https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.7.x/pom.xml#L78. In branch 3.7.x it set source/target Java version to 1.8.

Comment: Thank you both. 
I did check Liquibase website and release notes, and docs etc. but couldn't find anything related. So just checking if someone is aware of any unadvertised baseline changes. I know Java 7 is outdated.

Comment: @Zorglube On `https://www.liquibase.org` I also could not find this information in the release notes of [3.7](https://www.liquibase.org/2019/07/liquibase-3-7-0-released.html) nor somewhere else on the webpage. Do you know the a link to find it there?

Answer (score 2):

Comments above are correct. Liquibase 3.7 and greater require Java 1.8 or greater. This was not called out in the release notes, and it should have been.